# Screen messed up when resumes from suspend

Tags: unity, nvidia, 12.04

When ubuntu resumes from suspend the screen messed up!, I have installed correct drivers for the graphics card (nVidia geforce 6200 128mb agp) and updated to the latest. This also happens when switching user accounts without login off, I use Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit and my pc is intel p4 3.06Ghz HT 1mb cache LGA,1GB ddr1 400mhz, asus p5pe-vm MB, here are some screenshots. Please help

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggested steps to get back to a working desktop when you have graphics issues regardless of driver.

The steps I usually try are first <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> followed by  <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>.  In some cases this will get it working.

After that, if you're using unity-3d(the default) try `unity --replace &` in a terminal.  Basically that means launch a new unity to replace the old one.

Comment: You are a hero!!!!

Comment: I removed nvidia drivers, and now those issues are gone, but no effects:-(

Comment: I have the same problem. This may work, but it doesn't "just work." Is there a way to do this automatically after resuming from suspend? Or a way to fix whatever the problem is in the first place?

Comment: @Josh Wait for a driver patch or use supported hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem with Ubuntu 16.10, GTX 750 Ti and 4K monitor. `killall compiz` and waiting for it to respawn fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. If I go into Settings > Displays and click the Apply button, it resets the video and everything is fine again. There should be a better fix that this though.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. No 3rd party drivers installed. System > Details says my graphics is:  AMD TURKS (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.13.0-39-generic, LLVM 5.0.0)