# Suspend and resume not working on an HP dv7

Tags: power-management

this one is driving me nuts. My HP dv7 laptop isn't resuming from suspend and hybernate. On suspend - resume it leaves me with a black screen. On hibernate it succesfully loads the images and then it hangs....

I searched through internet and tried serveral things, but nothing seems to work for this HP dv7 on Ubuntu 12.04. With 11.10 it didn't work either.

- Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 450 @ 2.40GHz × 4
- VESA: Intel®Ironlake Mobile Graphics
- 64-bit

Comment: i have the same problem

Comment: see if this works for you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126660/screen-messed-up-when-resumes-from-suspend/126672#126672 it works for me

Comment: No, the CTRL-ALT combination doesn't respond. Only a black screen apears.

Comment: try the second part...after CTL-ALT-F1 login as the same user and run `unity --replace &`

Comment: Nothing happens. I can't login. The console doesn't respond only restarting the system helps. The /var/log/pm-suspend.log doesn't show any failures....
Where can I find the resume log??

Answer (score 0):

Hi please refer to my previous posts on how to fix this the last comment on this bug post:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/989674?comments=all

I have also answered it on the ask ubuntu forums here:
[Entire system freezing after pressing "Suspend"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128222/entire-system-freezing-after-pressing-suspend/135555#135555)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it helped the original post but it didn't for me.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on a Toshiba Z830. I remember when I installed it like 2 weeks ago suspend was not a problem. Then I wanted it to be able to hibernate and installed Tuxonice. It didn't work and removed it but I would say that since then I cannot suspend anymore. Besides when I do `uname -a` I get:

```
Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-26-generic-tuxonice #41~ppa1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Jun 30 08:47:46 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The kernel is still named after tuxonice.

I am not sure this belongs to this thread but definitely the solution given above does not help (I found an update from him in [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11926504) that also doesn't work for me).

I posted my problem somewhere else and it got solved:

- [How do I uninstall the TuxOnIce kernel in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161966/how-do-i-uninstall-the-tuxonice-kernel-in-12-04)

I wonder if the original post had some kernel issue too and the link above may be useful for him too.

Comment: I guess the question is hardware specific. Yours was a Toshiba and the problem probably caused by installing Tuxonice. The OP has a HP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with 12.04 LTS on HP Pavilion dv7. After hours of research and anger I read some article about nvidia drivers. I finally installed `nvidia-current` package via Synaptic which is not installed by default, restarted and everything works fine.