# Unable to resume after suspend

Tags: suspend, lenovo, ideapad

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 & everything about it is great except that it just won't resume after suspend. I've tried the suggestions listed in this thread [Entire system freezing after pressing "Suspend"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128222/entire-system-freezing-after-pressing-suspend) but none worked. I'm using Lenovo Y510P. I'm new to Ubuntu, or unix for that matter, so please let me know if there's anymore  information that I should be posting. Thanks.

**update**

I tried the suggestion by Dima on this post [How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation). The machine wakes up from hibernation but immediately the screen gives a screen like this

[image]

Wondering if this is an issue with the graphics card or something.

Comment: its obviously common lenovo problem, i have same issue with UBUNTU 14.10 and LENOVO Z50 70

Comment: Maybe the problem is an old kernel. Check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296423/linux-mint-18-suspend-issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A lot of graphic resume problems could be solved by doing the suspend/resume from the virtual console, so that after the resume a "refresh" is forced by the graphic drivers.

Check if the system suspend correctly from a virtual console:

1. switch to a virtual console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>
2. login with your user and password
3. suspend the system (either using the suspend key-combo for your system, or issuing the command `sudo /usr/sbin/pm-suspend`)
4. resume -> you should have a working prompt (exactly the same screens as before), otherwise see FAIL
5. switch to the graphic console with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>
6. if all is ok, problem solved! You can follow the instruction below [(from this answer)](https://askubuntu.com/a/387676/16395)  to make the switch automatic; otherwise, see FAIL

If something is still wrong...

FAIL: So the problem is another one --- I do not have that laptop so I can't really help a lot more. Maybe studying the content of file `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` can shed some light.

---

*How to make the switch automatic*

1. edit/create the file

   `gksudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/01_switchvt`
2. Put  this content in it:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   # Switch to a VC before suspending and back after resume

   case "$1" in
       resume|thaw)
           chvt 7
       ;;
       suspend|hibernate)
           chvt 1
       ;;
   esac
   ```
3. save and exit
4. make it executable:

   `sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/01_switchvt`

**Notice** in step 2, most of the installations will need the command `chvt 7` --- this is the same as pushing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to the graphic screen. If you need another key combo, change the "7" there accordingly.

Comment: I'm able to recover from virtual console. However, I wasn't able to make the switch automatic. But I guess I'll be using virtual console for the time being. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ah yes! I realized that's what I was missing. I've now used chmod 755 to set permissions of the file & it works perfectly fine! Thanks a ton :)

Comment: I tried both upvoting and adding a comment but I don't have enough reputation on this flavor of stackexchange yet.

Comment: with LENOVO Z50 70 same problem, but i cant even switch to console ctrl+alt+f1 when it happens ... display is turned on, but nothing shows up until i turn it off and on

Comment: same problem with hybernation and suspend ...

Comment: Had a similar problem in 14.04 on a Macbook with the Nouveau driver, and unfortunately this did not work. This did let me get to a login screen, whereas before I only saw my desktop background, but once logged in, everything was frozen. Trying to kill/restart gnome-shell was unsuccessful.

Comment: Thank you so very much! Although that auto script doesn't work for me, the above solution does (LENOVO Z50 70, with nvidia proprietary drivers). You sir made my day

Comment: @Mathlight I have the same problem with the same computer. Can you help me?

Comment: In more recent versions of Ubuntu use /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ instead of /etc/pm/sleep.d/