# 13.10 black screen after wake from suspend

Tags: suspend

I am running 13.10, when I try to wake my computer from suspend the screen doesn't seem to activate. Any pointers as to where I am going wrong? I just have to manually reboot the computer for it to come to life again!

Comment: Try to see if this answer help you: http://askubuntu.com/a/436389/16395 --- if it does, comment/modify the question, please. Anyway, you need to give much more info about your hardware; at least the graphic card you have and the drivers you are using.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the pointer. I just gave that a go to no luck. I am using an intel nuc with celeron processor. http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-board-dn2820fykh.html

Comment: Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: I really don't know --- you can try the other answers to the question I pointed before. BTW, please add the data of your computer to the question (better hint at it in the title, too --- try to be more search-friendly and see if you can attract some help more useful than mine...)

Comment: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436133/unable-to-resume-after-suspend/436389#436389) solves the question completely. Tested and worked on all ubuntu versions

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl+F1</kbd> to go to shell login "tty1" and enter your username and password
Then type
`sudo service lightdm restart`
and then enter your password again.
It'll do the trick.