# Can't login after sleep (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, login, suspend

I've got Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my laptop (Lenovo Z570), and it is fully updated. The trouble is that when I wake it from a sleep long enough to require entering my password to login, it won't let me enter my password. The field is there, and the cursor is blinking, but nothing happens when I type. The pointer works, so I can switch users to get back in, but that's the only way I can get to login.

Comment: Take a look at [this related question](http://askubuntu.com/q/436133/107450) was a fix on 12.04 may still work with 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once, and if memory serves it was an NVidia graphics glitch, not a login glitch. In my case I switched to another console (CTRL+SHIFT+F1), logged in there and upgraded to a newer NVidia graphics package - I think I was running 304 and upgraded to 331, rebooted and the login screen rendered correctly this time.

If you're running an Intel GPU, however, I suspect that won't be your problem.

If your machine has hybrid graphics like NVidia Optimus (combined NVidia and Intel GPU such as included in the Lenovo T410s), remember to install the Bumblebee package so it can manage it properly.

Comment: Yeah, my laptop has an Intel graphics chip, but I'll check to see if I need to update that package, just in case. Thanks

Comment: If you only have Intel HD graphics you should not install the NVIDIA driver.

Comment: Not planning to. I meant that I would check for an update to the Intel package