# Laptop hangs on exit of suspend mode when using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, laptop, suspend, asus, iso

I have an Asus S56CA Laptop that is using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS as a sole Operating System. Previous to this I was using Ubuntu 14.04 and had lots of unwanted documents, images, videos etc and also had picked up a few viruses. I decided the easiest way to go about resolving this issue was to do a complete clean install of Ubuntu. I downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS ISO (64 bit) from here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and created a bootable USB using the 'Startup Disk Creator' tool that comes pre-installed with Ubuntu on a brand-new 8 gigabyte USB. I then booted from this, installed the OS and installed the latest updates  with no issues. However, the only issue I have noticed is that my laptop will not wake from suspend. (Please Note that this was an issue present on the laptop before the clean install but I thought it was down to one of said viruses.) I know that this is a known issue but I though that this would have been fixed folllowing the latest updates. Does anyone know any way around these issues?

***EDIT:***

I should have mentioned that:

**- Upon opening the lid/clicking the power button once to resume from suspend:**
All is can see is a blank, black screen with my cursor which cannot be moved. No key provides a response apart from the power key to preform a hard reset.

**-Using the Terminal to suspend and resume:**
If I were to use the command `sudo pm-suspend` the laptop will suspend and resume before showing me the screen which I had entered the command on (shows the terminal and any other windows that were currently visible when command was executed) but I cannot interact with this in any way. Again, the only button that responds is the power key in order to preform a hard reset.

***PREVIOUS FIXES ATTEMPTS***

I have tried using a script that made the graphics card do a reboot (Using chvt1 and chvt7 I believe) but this just made the laptop unable to suspend at all. I have also tried using the fix mentioned here: [Unable to resume after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436133/unable-to-resume-after-suspend/436389#436389) but reached the area where it stated 'FAIL'. I tried using the code provided but it returns:

```
bash: /var/log/pm-suspend.log: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue also. I wake my computer up, unlock it, and it hangs. I don't know how to fix it, I just reboot the computer. I know that if you don't require a password after sleep, it wakes just fine.

Comment: I don't even get a chance to unlock mine, it hangs as soon as lid is opened/power button is pressed. Thanks for this information, I will use this as a temporary fix until someone can provide an answer/the issue is resolved :)

Comment: Only just got back to my laptop. Just turned off the need to have a password entered when waking from suspend but had the same result. Any other ideas?