# Mouse is trapped after standby/suspend

Tags: mouse, suspend, hibernate

System: ~$ uname -r
3.13.0-39-generic (Ubuntu 14.04 64 Bit)

After executing suspend my Lenovo Thinkpad T430 (Intel HD 4000 graphics) normally went into standby. By clicking the power button to reactivate i can succesfully type in my password and i'm back in the actual application (for example firefox). But it is not possible to activate another program by clicking on one of the starters on the left side. Also i cannot click on the menu top right corner. It's blocked. So i'am actual trapped in one application. :D

I am forced to do Str-Alt-Del to log out. After retyping my password and log in again the system works fine.

- I also have installed updated intel graphics driver by installing and
  executing Intel Graphics Installer for Linux/Ubuntu.
- Furthermore i tried another version of the package **pm-utils** **by forcing to 1.4.1-13**
  (trusty)
- Tried **sudo dpkg-reconfigure compiz**
- Log after pm-hibernate:

> ```
> > Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend:
> stop: Unknown instance: 
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend: not applicable.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
> Kernel modesetting video driver detected, not using quirks.
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
> kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend: success.
>
> Mi 5. Nov 22:24:18 CET 2014: performing suspend
> Mi 5. Nov 22:24:22 CET 2014: Awake.
> Mi 5. Nov 22:24:22 CET 2014: Running hooks for resume
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend:
>
> /dev/sda:
>  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
>  APM_level    = 254
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend: not applicable.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend:
> Reloaded unloaded modules.
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend:
> Selected interface 'wlan0'
> OK
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: success.
>
> Mi 5. Nov 22:24:22 CET 2014: Finished.
> Initial commandline parameters: 
> Mi 5. Nov 22:30:04 CET 2014: Running hooks for hibernate.
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging hibernate hibernate:
> Linux phil-ThinkPad-T430 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:30:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> Module                  Size  Used by
> nls_utf8               12557  1 
> isofs                  39837  1 
> ctr                    13049  3 
> ccm                    17773  3 
> pci_stub               12622  1 
> vboxpci                23194  0 
> vboxnetadp             25670  0 
> vboxnetflt             27613  0 
> vboxdrv               339502  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
> snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46368  1 
> snd_hda_codec_realtek    65580  1 
> uvcvideo               80885  0 
> videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
> videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
> videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
> videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
> rfcomm                 69160  0 
> snd_hda_intel          56451  3 
> bnep                   19624  2 
> intel_rapl             18773  0 
> bluetooth             391136  10 bnep,rfcomm
> x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
> intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
> coretemp               13435  0 
> snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
> kvm_intel             143148  0 
> kvm                   451729  1 kvm_intel
> snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
> snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
> crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
> crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
> ghash_clmulni_intel    13216  0 
> aesni_intel            55624  6 
> snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
> snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
> aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
> lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
> snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
> arc4                   12608  2 
> gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
> glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
> ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
> cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
> iwldvm                232285  0 
> snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
> binfmt_misc            17468  1 
> mac80211              630653  1 iwldvm
> thinkpad_acpi          81013  1 
> nvram                  14411  1 thinkpad_acpi
> snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
> snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
> joydev                 17381  0 
> serio_raw              13462  0 
> snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
> iwlwifi               169932  1 iwldvm
> i915                  783961  3 
> cfg80211              484040  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
> lpc_ich                21080  0 
> wmi                    19177  0 
> drm_kms_helper         55071  1 i915
> drm                   303102  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
> i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
> mei_me                 18627  0 
> snd                    69322  18 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,thinkpad_acpi,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
> parport_pc             32701  0 
> mei                    82276  1 mei_me
> ppdev                  17671  0 
> soundcore              12680  1 snd
> mac_hid                13205  0 
> lp                     17759  0 
> video                  19476  1 i915
> parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
> hid_generic            12548  0 
> usbhid                 52659  0 
> hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
> psmouse               106714  0 
> e1000e                254433  0 
> sdhci_pci              23172  0 
> ahci                   25819  3 
> libahci                32716  1 ahci
> sdhci                  43015  1 sdhci_pci
> ptp                    18933  1 e1000e
> pps_core               19382  1 ptp
>              Gesamt Belegt Frei Gemeinsam Puffer Cached
> Speicher:    5806868    1433288    4373580     138232      59384     655004
> -/+ Puffer/Cache:     718900    5087968
> Auslagerungsdatei:    5980156          0    5980156
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common hibernate hibernate:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate hibernate hibernate:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant hibernate hibernate:
> Selected interface 'wlan0'
> OK
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules hibernate hibernate: not applicable.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock hibernate hibernate: not applicable.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron hibernate hibernate:
> stop: Unknown instance: 
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm hibernate hibernate: not applicable.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler hibernate hibernate:
> Kernel modesetting video driver detected, not using quirks.
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend hibernate hibernate:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Mi 5. Nov 22:30:04 CET 2014: performing hibernate
> Mi 5. Nov 22:30:45 CET 2014: Awake.
> Mi 5. Nov 22:30:45 CET 2014: Running hooks for thaw
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend thaw hibernate:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm thaw hibernate:
>
> /dev/sda:
>  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
>  APM_level    = 254
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock thaw hibernate: not applicable.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules thaw hibernate:
> Reloaded unloaded modules.
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant thaw hibernate:
> Selected interface 'wlan0'
> OK
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate thaw hibernate:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common thaw hibernate:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Mi 5. Nov 22:30:45 CET 2014: Finished.
> Initial commandline parameters: 
> Mi 5. Nov 22:34:34 CET 2014: Running hooks for hibernate.
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging hibernate hibernate:
> Linux phil-ThinkPad-T430 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:30:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> Module                  Size  Used by
> nls_utf8               12557  1 
> isofs                  39837  1 
> ctr                    13049  2 
> ccm                    17773  2 
> pci_stub               12622  1 
> vboxpci                23194  0 
> vboxnetadp             25670  0 
> vboxnetflt             27613  0 
> vboxdrv               339502  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
> snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46368  1 
> snd_hda_codec_realtek    65580  1 
> uvcvideo               80885  0 
> videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
> videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
> videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
> videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
> rfcomm                 69160  0 
> snd_hda_intel          56451  3 
> bnep                   19624  2 
> intel_rapl             18773  0 
> bluetooth             391136  10 bnep,rfcomm
> x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
> intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
> coretemp               13435  0 
> snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
> kvm_intel             143148  0 
> kvm                   451729  1 kvm_intel
> snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
> snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
> crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
> crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
> ghash_clmulni_intel    13216  0 
> aesni_intel            55624  4 
> snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
> snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
> aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
> lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
> snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
> arc4                   12608  2 
> gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
> glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
> ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
> cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
> iwldvm                232285  0 
> snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
> binfmt_misc            17468  1 
> mac80211              630653  1 iwldvm
> thinkpad_acpi          81013  1 
> nvram                  14411  1 thinkpad_acpi
> snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
> snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
> joydev                 17381  0 
> serio_raw              13462  0 
> snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
> iwlwifi               169932  1 iwldvm
> i915                  783961  3 
> cfg80211              484040  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
> lpc_ich                21080  0 
> wmi                    19177  0 
> drm_kms_helper         55071  1 i915
> drm                   303102  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
> i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
> mei_me                 18627  0 
> snd                    69322  18 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,thinkpad_acpi,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
> parport_pc             32701  0 
> mei                    82276  1 mei_me
> ppdev                  17671  0 
> soundcore              12680  1 snd
> mac_hid                13205  0 
> lp                     17759  0 
> video                  19476  1 i915
> parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
> hid_generic            12548  0 
> usbhid                 52659  0 
> hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
> psmouse               106714  0 
> e1000e                254433  0 
> sdhci_pci              23172  0 
> ahci                   25819  3 
> libahci                32716  1 ahci
> sdhci                  43015  1 sdhci_pci
> ptp                    18933  1 e1000e
> pps_core               19382  1 ptp
>              Gesamt Belegt Frei Gemeinsam Puffer Cached
> Speicher:    5806868    1675228    4131640     154480     109192     704036
> -/+ Puffer/Cache:     862000    4944868
> Auslagerungsdatei:    5980156          0    5980156
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common hibernate hibernate:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate hibernate hibernate:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant hibernate hibernate:
> Selected interface 'wlan0'
> OK
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules hibernate hibernate: not applicable.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock hibernate hibernate: not applicable.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron hibernate hibernate:
> stop: Unknown instance: 
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm hibernate hibernate: not applicable.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler hibernate hibernate:
> Kernel modesetting video driver detected, not using quirks.
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video hibernate hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend hibernate hibernate:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend hibernate hibernate: success.
>
> Mi 5. Nov 22:34:35 CET 2014: performing hibernate
> Mi 5. Nov 22:35:13 CET 2014: Awake.
> Mi 5. Nov 22:35:13 CET 2014: Running hooks for thaw
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend thaw hibernate:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm thaw hibernate:
>
> /dev/sda:
>  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
>  APM_level    = 254
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock thaw hibernate: not applicable.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules thaw hibernate:
> Reloaded unloaded modules.
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant thaw hibernate:
> Selected interface 'wlan0'
> OK
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate thaw hibernate:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common thaw hibernate:
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change thaw hibernate:
> /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change thaw hibernate: success.
>
> Mi 5. Nov 22:35:13 CET 2014: Finished.
> ```

Need some help. I'm already new to Linux. :(
Thanks.

Comment: Would switching to a virtual terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F1) and back (Ctrl-Alt-F7) help? Maybe you need to suspend from a virtual console, as in http://askubuntu.com/a/436389/16395

Comment: Which one? So that I can put it as an answer... ;-)

Comment: I followed your link and processed step 1-6. Next i wrote the script "How to make the switch automatic". All works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably due to an incorrect reset of the graphic card/device after suspend and/or resume.

In these cases, often [performing the suspend/resume from a Virtual Console](https://askubuntu.com/a/436389/16395) helps.

(In the link above, you have detailed instructions).