# Acer Aspire S7 on 14.04 | Frozen after Sleep

Tags: suspend, acer

Every third or fourth time that I resume my Acer Aspire S7-392 (suspending works every time), the screen is completely frozen, though my mouse can move.  There is nothing that I can do to make it responsive except going to TTY1 and entering `sudo service lightdm restart`.  This is obviously not desirable behavior.

When I resume, there is a bug report that has the same error message as this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/1305699.  I have CC'd myself to that bug.

Given that it's been open and unassigned for over a year, is there any workaround to getting my suspend working?  I wish I had enough knowledge about upowerd to go in and fix it myself :)

---

EDIT: Output of `lscpi -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller [8086:0a04] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC [8086:9c31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 [8086:9c3a] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:9c14] (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 [8086:9c26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9c43] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] [8086:282a] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9c22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 6b)
```

Comment: Hello, can you run `lspci -nn` in you terminal and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/598138/edit) your question with the output from it? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried http://askubuntu.com/a/436389/16395 ?

Comment: @Rmano - I'll try that next time it freezes and will report back.

Comment: @rhefner1 do not wait a freeze --- it's important to do both the suspend and the resume from the VC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had any trouble in the past few days with the link to the fix from @Rmano.

To get it working, check out [Unable to resume after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436133/unable-to-resume-after-suspend/436389#436389) and follow the "How to make the switch automatic" section.