# Kubuntu 14.04.2 laptop freezes on black screen after waking from sleep mode

Tags: kubuntu, dell, suspend, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron N7110 laptop, running Kubuntu 14.04.2.  Whenever I put the laptop in sleep mode, it goes right to sleep, as intended.  But when I wake the laptop from sleep mode by pressing the power button or opening the laptop lid, that's when problems arise.  When I wake the laptop from sleep mode, I see a login screen, but as soon as I type a character with the keyboard, the screen immediately turns black, with nothing visible except the mouse cursor, which can be moved around with the mouse.  From this point it is impossible to log back in to the computer, and I am forced to power off the laptop completely to log back in.  This is particularly frustrating!  Does anybody know why this is happening?  Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Have you checked http://askubuntu.com/a/436389/16395 ?

Comment: @Rmano, I have indeed checked that answer and the suggested fix doesn't help.  When I wake up the computer from sleep mode while in the virtual console, there are a bunch of error messages that appear.  The console appears to work at first, but after trying to execute a command errors just appear.  Also, when I switch back to the GUI I get the same black screen I mentioned before, with the working mouse cursor.  I had Amarok opened before I suspended and when I woke it up and switched back to the GUI Amarok was visible against the plain black screen (no KDE interface to be seen).

Comment: Sorry, can't help any more. Please add the info you put in the comment to your question and hope someone has solved the same problem --- adding the error messages you see could be of some help. Good luck!