# Black Borders - Different suspend commands?

Tags: unity, nvidia, suspend

I have the popular "Black window borders" problem after coming back from standby when closing the lid. I use a NVIDIA graphics card and Ubuntu 15.04.

The surprising thing is that when going to standby by clicking on the context menu in the top right corner and resuming from standby the windows DO NOT have the black border problem - ONLY when i go to standby closing the lid.

My questions: 1. Are there different scripts that control how to notebook is going to suspend mode (closing the lid vs context menu). 2. If so can we replace the suspend script when closing the lid to the same that is triggered when clicking the context menu in the  top right corner?

(Going back to the nouveau driver is not an option because then LibreOffice crashes on certain occasions - this never happens with the NVIDIA driver. Also I don't want to use Ctrl+F1 then Ctrl-F7 every time ...)

Comment: Try the following: switch to a virtual console (ctrl-alt-F1), then close the lid. Wait for suspension; resume and then switch back to the graphical interface (typically ctrl-alt-f7). Do you have the black borders or not? If not, you can try http://askubuntu.com/a/436389/16395