# No display after resuming from suspend

Tags: 14.04, suspend, hp

The laptop is able to suspend. After resuming from suspend, there is simply no display, the screen remains off. Based on all the other answers, I have tried the various **Ctrl+Alt+Fn** (1 - 12) combinations as well as **Ctrl+Alt+Del**. There is no terminal, no error message, no nothing. The only thing that does happen is the fans go louder and faster.

The model/make of the laptop is HP 630 Notebook PC.

Comment: Please add model and make of the laptop. Moreover, the "virtual console" method is: switch to a VC, suspend, then resume, switch back to graphic, See http://askubuntu.com/a/436389/16395

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to update the BIOS.

The old BIOS which didn't work was version F.19. 
It worked after updating to version F.39.

Comment: This is the first step you should do always. BIOS are (always --- search "bios" in http://fortunes.cat-v.org/kernelnewbies/) buggy, updating means that it will be (most of the time) a bit less buggy.  +1, but please fix the question.

Comment: @Rmano yes, indeed, that was my bad. Sorry, but I don't understand how to fix the question, I'm rather new here. Should I just delete it instead?

Comment: If you simply edit (click here: http://askubuntu.com/posts/659483/edit ) your question adding the model and make of your laptop, this Q&A could be useful to other people --- please do it! Also doing the same in the answer, and naming the exact version of the BIOS that made your laptop work, would be useful.  Think future searches!

Comment: @Rmano thanks! I know how to edit, but didn't know what to. Done.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get anything on a screen even after powering off and on, possibly you should try to clear CMOS but this better do in service centre.

If you can see at least BIOS post messages immediately after powering on but then it goes blank screen, this means something wrong with you OS and you should try to boot Ubuntu from Live USB and then recover it.

If you can successfully boot as usual but you have issues only resuming from suspend this is just a bug in kernel or in graphic drivers. You should write a bug report on appropriate bug tracker previously identifying the source of the problem.

Comment: That was my first hunch as well, and what most of the other questions/answers say. But in this instance, it turned out to be a rather simple case of an outdated BIOS.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. In my case, I discovered a method for this: start swiping the touch pad fully and very fast, **immediately** after opening the lid.