# Script to mute laptop when suspend button is pressed

Tags: bash, suspend, hibernate, 15.10

I am wanting to make my laptop mute its sound when I suspend, as well as hibernate. I have attempted this by writing a simple script and placing it in my `/etc/pm/sleep.d` folder and making the script executable. However when I suspend my laptop nothing happens. Can someone tell me what I need to do to make this goal of mine to work?

```
#!/bin/bash
#script to make  system mute sound on  suspend


    amixer -q -D pulse sset Master toggle
```

Comment: `sleep.d` scripts must have quite strict names and structure.... See if http://askubuntu.com/a/436389/16395 helps for hints

Comment: So then would this be what you are talking about then?
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12941216/

Answer (score 1):

Here's how the script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` should look like. Name it `20_mute_audio`

```
#! /bin/sh
case $1 in
     suspend|suspend_hybrid|hibernate)
         amixer -q -D pulse sset Master toggle
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Probably --- although I will use "mute" instead of toggle (you never know your status when entering there). And remember to `chmod +x` the script, otherwise it will not executed.

Comment: This is not working for me. I'm using 17.10.

Comment: Try placing it in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/