# How to mute laptop when the lid closes?

Tags: sound, suspend, laptop, events, mute

I would like to mute my laptop everytime its lid closes by running the following command:

```
amixer set Master mute
```

I found a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689603/script-to-mute-laptop-when-suspend-button-is-pressed) asked more than 2 years ago which didn't work for me on Ubuntu 17.10. I also found this documentation called [LaptopLidAndDockScripts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopLidAndDockScripts) for running general scripts when certain events happen,but it is a little cumbersome. Is there a quick way to add this feature?