# How do I uninstall the TuxOnIce kernel in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, uninstall, tuxonice

I recently installed tuxonice on a Toshiba z830. I have ubuntu 12.04 (kernel was: 3.2.0-26) I wanted to be able to hibernate, which I consider to be a basic thing a OS should allow you to do. Well, it didn't work...but they already tell you it may not so I removed it. For doing all these I followed:

[Problem with Hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151640/problem-with-hibernation)

After uninstalling I switched off the laptop and after this I started to have several problems. The first one was that Cisco VPN didn't work anymore and then I realised that I could not even suspend my laptop. I found very strange that after removing tuxonice I still had this:

/lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic-tuxonice/

The VPN problem could be solved by just copying from my previous kernel: 3.2.0-26-generic/CiscoVPN/ into the tuxonice one. Not very elegant but works.

Now, for the suspend problem (and the previous too) I can hold Shift when starting and select my old kernel and then suspend works again.

In my opinion tuxonice was not correctly uninstalled as it left that kernel behind and worse: ubuntu uses it if I do not take action. I have these work arounds....and here is my question:

**how can I delete this tuxonice kernel safely?** If you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Removing TuxOnIce**

- Start the terminal and enter:

  ```
   sudo apt-get --purge remove tuxonice-userui linux-generic-tuxonice linux-headers-generic-tuxonice
  ```
- If you tried that, then try

  ```
   sudo apt-get --purge remove tuxonice\*
  ```
- Then restart

Comment: thank you for the prompt reply. I ran both commands but I still have the same problem. I still have the strange:  /lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic-tuxonice/   and I cannot suspend the computer. When I press the shift key when starting Ubuntu I still see the turnonice kernel and have to choose my previous one to get suspend working :-(

Comment: @Lluis: Can you run sudo update-grub please? Then reboot and see if you still get the tuxonice kernel in the list.

Comment: Victory! when I executed your two first commands I was doing something else and didn't realised that the second one didn't do anything. There was a typo spelling tuxonice. I realised this later and ran it again. Then your very last command with update-grub and it worked! thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lluis: sorry about the typo! Glad it worked, and hopefully hibernation gets officially restored sometime in the future...

Comment: thanks a lot. I also hope it works soon. It is very important for people using laptops as laptops. Until then I am happy I can suspend it :-)